# Mountain Gravity

Tags: newtonian-gravity, mass, earth, geophysics

Because gravity weakens the farther you are from the mass. Would standing on the side of a mountain change the direction gravity pulls on you because you are closer to the mass of the mountain then the mass of the Earth?? Could this explain why sometime when you are going down a mountain it feels like you are traveling on a flat plain?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed it would! This fact was actually used to determine the average density of the Earth in 1774, in an expedition known as the Schiehallion Experiment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schiehallion_experiment.

This deflection is pretty tiny, though, and so probably the reason you feel like you're traveling down a flat plain is that though mountains are pretty tall, their slopes tend to be much gentler than you'd expect looking at them from a distance.

Comment: It is also used to 'weigh' mountains and discover mineral or oil reserves https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravimetry

Comment: Unclassified deflection data are here: http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm2008/anomalies_dov.html

Comment: Semi-relevant [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/852/)